# Delete field office for all users SP2013

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-property, delete

Is there a way to delete the values of User Profile Property *Office* for all users via Powershell or CA?

Comment: are u on sharepoint online or farm?

Comment: If Central Admin exists, it's on premise (says CA in post) @SalvatoreDiFazio

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:  Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Service Applications > User Profile Service (whatever you have it named as) > Manage User Properties  ... Scroll down until you find 'Office' then just delete it and recreate it.  Its just a string field, nothing to it.  Unless you have it mapped to AD, then you might have to remap it.  Or if its not needed, just delete it and move on.

Option 2: *Recommended*  There is a powershell command to set user profile values: The user launching this must have both admin and permission set, to check this, highlight your service in CA, then on the top ribbon you will see 'Administrators' and 'Permissions' just open both to make sure that the account is in both:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$Site = Get-SPSite -Limit 1
$ServiceContext = Get-SPServiceContext($Site)
$ProfileManager = new-object   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)
$Profiles = $ProfileManager.GetEnumerator()

foreach($profile in $Profiles) {
  $profile["Office"].Value = "";
  $profile.Commit();
}
```

This line:  $Site = Get-SPSite -Limit 1 was a little trick I picked up from the "Scripting Guys', figured I'd give credit where credit is due.

Comment: Go with Option 2, I would not delete the out of the box fields from the User Profile Service.

Comment: Agreed, I meant to put *Recommended* next to option 2, thanks for calling it out.  Personally, I am starting to love powershell, but that is another conversation haha.